# OLE Action Error al generar PPT con VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Muy buenas,

Resulta que tengo un documento excel con algunas macros, donde, una de ellas se encarga de generar un PPT a partir de información del xlsm.

El problema es que **a veces** surge un error cuando VBA intenta abrir la app de PPT, pero no es algo que ocurre siempre, solo eventualmente.

Cuando el error ocurre, VBA se queda en bucle intentando abrir el PPT, dando un mensaje de OLE Action Error.

La única forma de "solucionar" el error y parar el bucle es entrar en el administrador de tareas y finalizar PPT. Una vez finalizado VBA dará un error, y ese error salta en la siguiente línea.

```
'Abrir PwrPnt
    
        Set PwrPnt = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
        With PwrPnt
        .Visible = True
        .Presentations.Open ruta2 & "\" & nombreCOM & "\6_Carpeta\" & num_Archivo & "_Presentacion" & ".pptx"
        .ActivePresentation.UpdateLinks
        End With
```

Comment: ¿Puede que ocurra eventualmente porque no cerráis bien las instancias de PowerPoint anteriores, que tienen el archivo abierto? ¿Limpias todas las variables objeto una vez terminado el código?

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes Cuando te refieres a limpiar las varibales objeto, en este caso te refieres a PwrPnt, no? Si es así, no, no se suelen limpiar. También es verdad que el fallo suele ocurrir, una vez más, no siempre, la primera vez que se genera un PwrPnt.

Comment: Deberíais limpiar siempre las variables y asegurar que las instancias están finalizadas. Que sea la primera vez que se genera el archivo no significa que sea la primera instancia ya abierta si nunca las cerráis.